# Interactive nodes in vis js network

Tags: vis.js-network, vis.js

When node is selected I want to add a icon on node and on icon click I want to give options to edit or deleted selected node. Is this possible or how to implement this in Vis js?

Comment: http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/manipulationEditEdgeNoDrag.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the click event or nodeSelected.
like this:

```
network.on('click', function (properties) {    
  selection = properties.nodes

  if (selection > 0) {
    var node_sel = nodes.get([selection])[0];
    if(node_sel['selected']){
      alert('add you buttons');
    }
    else{
      alert('change the style here');
      node_sel['selected'] = true;
      node_sel['shape'] = 'box';
      nodes.update(node_sel);
      var msg = JSON.stringify(nodes.get([selection]))
      alert(msg);
    }
  }
});
```

see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BhUeNjjCTDnKdSv5iSmo?p=preview), instead of the alerts put your code.